# C# HttpWebRequest Post form data with special string

Tags: c#, html, httpwebrequest, http-post

I'm trying to post form data to an external url to retrieve a html response.
When I try to post these values with a html form element in an .html file, it works fine.
However, when trying to post the same values with C# HttpWebRequest, it doesn't work.
The problematic variable is this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value='2015-08-19 13:30:00:::2015-08-19 16:40:00:::Estarder 1:::V:::VAI:::AAA:::460:::02:10:00:::CRJ:::V,Y:::::::::Z8:::Santa Cruz (VVI):::Salta(SLA)'>
```

That is the hidden field in the html form I'm using. When I send this "id" value as empty or wrong I get an empty string result instead of the expected html.

In C# code, I always get an empty string as response. This is my C# code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.anywebsite.com/reser/server/actu_status.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            string strNew = "&it=" + it + "&tipo_new=1&id=" + inputValue + "&monto=0&mon=";

            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strNew);

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I think encoding of this "inputValue" could be related to this, I tried these 2 ways:

```
1)  string strNew = "&it=" + it + "&tipo_new=1&id=" + inputValue + "&monto=0&mon=";

2)   string strNew = "&it=" + it + "&tipo_new=1&id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inputValue) + "&monto=0&mon=";
```

But none of these worked.

Do you have an idea what could be causing this empty string result?
Note that in web browser I also get the empty response when the "id" hidden input field has incorrect data.

Could there be a special encoding to be used there with ":::" characters?

Reviewing both calls (one .html file, another c# code) with Fiddler, the difference seems to be the "()" characters:
Html file call:

```
 3a%3a%3aSanta+Cruz+(VVI)%3a%3a%3aSalta(SLA)&monto=0&mon=
```

C# request sent:

```
 3A%3ASanta+Cruz+%28VVI%29%3A%3A%3ASalta%28SLA%29&monto=0&mon=
```

The encoding is not working for "()" characters? Any idea it could affect?

Comparing the headers :

```
POST https://www.anysite.com/reserva3/server/actu_estado.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.anysite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 380
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: null
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: WebAmaszonas=12a620133f447d1fd126c3bc176eb411; 20011920910-20150729143408-157141320855b91ca0074937-00865209=d433a027559697ffab682c23d799b0a6; 20011920910-20150729145250-68716839655b921024d6852-68684734=236496c8c7338b2f627a8ef232e594ad; 20011920910-20150729145319-101832047555b9211fbac1b4-84013043=462e294432435993d6abd781afedbe83; 20011920910-20150729145353-64952403855b92141797c34-27814538=a53da15223e0aa3738f11287b3e865ba; 20011920910-20150729145413-186346569255b921550c42a1-25690349=761611e26d9a55fd942f9ef096a3f082; 20011920910-20150729151718-96356722455b926bed246b0-24253581=e982ad1989a3d8435c6ae9e5fe19becc; 20011920910-20150729152154-11483789755b927d29a89c7-69865088=d5db38b9fdc3129fb272d2443375cf05; 20011920910-20150729152639-202823217355b928efe950f6-26854157=ca2f211d604ed43e1241d60c6542eb45; 20011920910-20150729152721-101593653455b929195ff4e0-55606804=6fabc92e9a3055fd4ac093cc33279d06; 20011920910-20150729153742-188056231255b92b8686f940-62606835=2e96f159b24b5b530b8985c1633a7534; 20011920910-20150729164914-64775098455b93c4a72d2e1-66426174=c585a55b2be8a312999c204f2591182a; 20011920910-20150729174029-113315944155b9484d134e05-75659750=224ec629dc27eee2287407578698ecff; 20011920910-20150729175035-123576351955b94aabac5d80-96847521=9d49f53a42c274351a9ea08856fec884; 20011920910-20150730110547-80615724155ba3d4b1ddde5-79868945=3e367e93767d39dae60037815ce5dc98; 20011920910-20150730110846-190316769455ba3dfe9ae3b8-00355181=cc2757b9bfd61f8da604057d098365c4; 20011920910-20150730120640-153925119555ba4b905daad6-58863984=fbf9b9189f8eb5c8c699353811206009; 20011920910-20150730155822-106183958655ba81dea52c27-39061829=955ac586630dacfd7958a2c945b517b3; __utma=44289076.1245823098.1438112030.1438271798.1438352283.5; __utmc=44289076; __utmz=44289076.1438271798.4.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); 20011920910-20150731101839-161050305155bb83bfc580f6-88478058=f4f290a7c96f10d6a251cc76c863faeb; 20011920910-20150731101913-144151518355bb83e1e874b3-12891534=8cd2dfa83c7bb6a4a8e9e9f26cb1e08e; 20011920910-20150731101951-195196827255bb8407a66238-65768491=9788783fa71200d225307d55585675d3; 20011920910-20150731102004-27173017555bb8414516340-71888646=820389de93795e6c94efabead492d845; 20011920910-20150731102028-97871570555bb842c84a2a0-94655428=2498720cc1ac2ee970c5e7e10952562c; 20011920910-20150731104252-143815792155bb896c959082-24175470=61bd70cec2d70aa254e099f7a718c5ff; 20011920910-20150731105957-195345078055bb8d6d7f2078-02814471=c5c0b192d70d36cd8303267f2bce8925; 20011920910-20150731104252-143815792155bb896c959082-24175470a=f70bc817d6362383b9bc1fa240396fe1; 20011920910-20150731133128-214572938755bbb0f04252a9-82382000=dd4dfbb4a1e3ea0e56e35256308ce08e; 20011920910-20150731152546-201600117255bbcbba049567-54330748=7bae974ce7eb9325188f333fb1812b5f

 it=20011920910-20150731152546-201600117255bbcbba049567-54330748&tipo_new=1&id=11%3A30%3A00%3A%3A%3A16%3A40%3A00%3A%3A%3A2015-08-19+13%3A30%3A00%3A%3A%3A2015-08-19+16%3A40%3A00%3A%3A%3AEscalas+1%3A%3A%3AV%3A%3A%3AVVI%3A%3A%3ASLA%3A%3A%3A460%3A%3A%3A02%3A10%3A00%3A%3A%3ACRJ%3A%3A%3AV%2CY%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AZ8%3A%3A%3ASanta+Cruz+%28VVI%29%3A%3A%3ASalta%28SLA%29&monto=0&mon=
```

C# call:

```
 POST https://www.anysite.com/reservar/server/actu_estado.php HTTP/1.1
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
 Cache-Control: max-age=0
 Origin:  
 Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
 Host: www.anysite.com
 Cookie: 20011920910-20150731161313-197603319955bbd6d90fbb13-41505311=4e901d35a856baef9b00ed3500d89113
 Content-Length: 384
 Connection: Keep-Alive

 it=20011920910-20150731161313-197603319955bbd6d90fbb13-41505311&tipo_new=1&id=13%3a30%3a00%3a%3a%3a16%3a40%3a00%3a%3a%3a2015-08-14+13%3a30%3a00%3a%3a%3a2015-08-14+16%3a40%3a00%3a%3a%3aEscalas+1%3a%3a%3aV%3a%3a%3aVVI%3a%3a%3aSLA%3a%3a%3a460%3a%3a%3a02%3a10%3a00%3a%3a%3aCRJ%3a%3a%3aH%2cV%2cY%3a%3a%3a%3a%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aZ8%3a%3a%3aSanta+Cruz+%28VVI%29%3a%3a%3aSalta%28SLA%29&monto=0&mon=
```

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare the results... You'll see what you do different with HttpWebRequest

Comment: @thanks EZI , I edited the question to provide Fiddler comparison.

Comment: What about other header fields? `User-Agent` , `Cookies` etc.

Comment: I added all the headers to match the browser request headers. Also, the cookies are being stored in CookiesContainer after a previous call. 
However, still receiving empty response. ContentLength = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all your data with System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode.

```
string strNew = "&it=" + it + "&tipo_new=1&id=" + inputValue + "&monto=0&mon=";
strNew = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Q: The encoding is not working for "()" characters?*

The encoding **is** working just as expected. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` is correctly encoding `'('` as `'%28'` and `')'` as '%29'`

---

*Q: Any idea it could affect?*

It *should not* have any effect. From [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt),

> "Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>    reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>    unencoded within a URL.
>
> On the other hand, characters that are not required to be encoded
>    (including alphanumerics) may be encoded within the scheme-specific
>    part of a URL, as long as they are not being used for a reserved
>    purpose."

---

The client side code you've posted looks fine. I was able to use your code and successfully pass the string to a server. So on the server side if I do the following,

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
string inputString = "2015-08-19 13:30:00:::2015-08-19 16:40:00:::Estarder 1:::V:::VAI:::AAA:::460:::02:10:00:::CRJ:::V,Y:::::::::Z8:::Santa Cruz (VVI):::Salta(SLA)";
if (httpRequest.Form["id"] == inputString)
  return Ok("Good");
```

Then I get `responseString` as "Good" (as expected)

Now why your server is not responding correctly is a separate question and I think you'll need to give details of the server side handling of your request.

Also, you are focusing on the `inputValue` string but are you sure the other parts of that `strNew`  string are not a problem (for instance, what's the `it` string)?

Comment: the it is a token value, I know it is right because server returns a different exception message when its value is incorrect.